# how to use timespan in the component of blazor server app and convert to 12 hour format

Tags: html, blazor, datetime-format, blazor-server-side, timespan

> My requirements are to add timeslot settings , edit and show that timeslots
> fields from the database are :
> 1.ID(short)
> 2.FromTime (TimeSpan)
> 3.ToTime(TimeSpan)
> 4.DisplayTime(string)
>
> Model CLass:

```
        public short TimeSlotID { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan FromTime { get; set; }
  

      public TimeSpan ToTime { get; set; }
```

> Database Read:

```
 yield return new TimeSlotModel
                    {
                        TimeSlotID = reader.GetInt16("TimeSlotID"),
                        FromTime = (TimeSpan)reader["FromTime"],
                        ToTime = (TimeSpan)reader["ToTime"],
                   
                        DisplayText = reader.SafeGetString("DisplayText"),
};
```

> Razor page

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="TimeSlotID">TimeSlotID</label>
                   
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label for="FromTime">FromTime</label>
                   
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="ToTime">ToTime</label>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="DisplayText">DisplayText</label>
                   @item.DisplayText 
                   
                </div>
            </div>
I found it difficult to use any components to read and add or edit coz its Timespan .
i used datetimepicker but i dont know how to convert that to timespan while saving that to the database.Can anyone help solve this one.
```

thank you!

Comment: A TimeSpan is a length of time.  A DateTime is a moment in time.  Are you sure you want a timeslot to have something like from 4 hours to 8 hours, rather than from 4pm to 8pm?

Comment: i want that in 12 hour format .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution binds to a DateTimeOffset property that sets your models timespans.

`Index.razor`

```
@page "/"

<input type="time" @bind-value="FromTime" />
<input type="time" @bind-value="ToTime" />
<hr />

@ConvertTo12HourFormat(SomeModel.FromTime) - @ConvertTo12HourFormat(SomeModel.ToTime)
```

`Index.razor.cs`

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

public partial class Index : ComponentBase
{
    readonly DateTimeOffset aDate = new DateTime(2020, 01, 01);
    public SomeModel SomeModel { get; set; } = new SomeModel();
    public DateTimeOffset FromTime
    {
        get { return aDate.Add(SomeModel.FromTime); }
        set { SomeModel.FromTime = value.Subtract(aDate); }
    }
    public DateTimeOffset ToTime
    {
        get { return aDate.Add(SomeModel.ToTime); }
        set { SomeModel.ToTime = value.Subtract(aDate); }
    }
    public string ConvertTo12HourFormat(TimeSpan time) => aDate.Add(time).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
}
```

`SomeModel.cs`

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public short TimeSlotID { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan FromTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ToTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hello, is that possible to use datetimepicker in razor page and convrt that to timespan while inserting that value to the database??

Comment: hello @Brian Parker  im getting error on it. values are zero and its not saving to database

Comment: @Aweelmarchons this is a different issue post it as another question with details.